# How to run self executing JS scripts in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and this is something I haven't had the need to do in any other Framework either, so I could use any and all suggestions :)

I'm trying to make a React component that replicates/encapsulates the responsive functionality shown here: 
https://www.adtile.me/fixed-nav/
Which was made with plain JS (I have a limited understanding of JS so far so this is my holdup).

So far what I've done is essentially copy over the index.html file from the github mentioned on the link, and rendered that component in my App.js main component. The problem I'm having now is I can't figure out the React approach for importing a JS script in the case where it would normally be included in a  tag. In their repo, they are utilizing a total of 4 scripts to achieve the responsive nature of the webpage, all loaded within index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Adtile Fixed Nav</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Adtile">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <a href="#home" class="logo" data-scroll>Fixed Nav</a>
      <nav class="nav-collapse">
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-item active"><a href="#home" data-scroll>Home</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#about" data-scroll>About</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#projects" data-scroll>Projects</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#blog" data-scroll>Blog</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="home">
      <h1>Fixed Nav</h1>
      <p>The code and examples are hosted on GitHub and can be <a href="https://github.com/adtile/fixed-nav">found from here</a>. Read more about the approach from&nbsp;<a href="http://blog.adtile.me/2014/03/03/responsive-fixed-one-page-navigation/">our&nbsp;blog</a>.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="about">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="projects">
      <h1>Projects</h1>
    </section>

    <section id="blog">
      <h1>Blog</h1>
    </section>

    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried loading them the same way in my NavBar component (in the jsx template) but I don't think they're loading right because the responsive nature isn't working.

I also tried to put the scripts as their own files in my project (just like they have it) and then do import "responsive-nav.js" in my NavBar component before importing React. This made me feel like I was getting somewhere, but the scripts generate many compile time errors when imported this way:

Failed to compile.

./src/components/NavBar/fixed-responsive-nav.js
  Line 28:5:    'FastClick' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 31:5:    'smoothScroll' is not defined   no-undef
  Line 34:22:   'responsiveNav' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 136:11:  Unexpected use of 'history'     no-restricted-globals
  Line 137:9:   Unexpected use of 'history'     no-restricted-globals
  Line 160:11:  Unexpected use of 'location'    no-restricted-globals
  Line 165:15:  Unexpected use of 'history'     no-restricted-globals
  Line 166:13:  Unexpected use of 'history'     no-restricted-globals

This is the output when trying to import one of the scripts (fixed-responsive-nav.js). I thought I could resolve the errors like 'FastClick' is not defined by importing that script that I thought it was trying to reference, fastclick.js. However, this did not resolve any of the conflicts. Here is fixed-responsive-nav.js to get an idea of what kinda script I'm working with (all scripts available on the above link):

```js
/* =============================================
 *
 *   FIXED RESPONSIVE NAV
 *
 *   (c) 2014 @adtileHQ
 *   http://www.adtile.me
 *   http://twitter.com/adtilehq
 *
 *   Free to use under the MIT License.
 *
 * ============================================= */

(function () {

  "use strict";

  // Feature test to rule out some older browsers
  if ("querySelector" in document && "addEventListener" in window) {

    // forEach method, that passes back the stuff we need
    var forEach = function (array, callback, scope) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        callback.call(scope, i, array[i]);
      }
    };

    // Attach FastClick to remove the 300ms tap delay
    FastClick.attach(document.body);

    // Init smooth scrolling
    smoothScroll.init();

    // Init Responsive Nav
    var navigation = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse", {

      // Close the navigation when it's tapped
      closeOnNavClick: true
    });

    // Create a Mask
    var mask = document.createElement("div");
    mask.className = "mask";

    // Append the mask inside <body>
    document.body.appendChild(mask);

    // Disable mask transitions on Android to boost performance
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) !== null) {
      document.documentElement.className += " android";
    }

    // Find navigation links and save a reference to them
    var nav = document.querySelector(".nav-collapse ul"),
      links = nav.querySelectorAll("[data-scroll]");

    // "content" will store all the location cordinates
    var content;

    // Set up an array of locations which we store in "content"
    var setupLocations = function () {
      content = [];
      forEach(links, function (i, el) {
        var href = links[i].getAttribute("href").replace("#", "");
        content.push(document.getElementById(href).offsetTop + 200);
      });
    };

    // call locations set up once
    setupLocations();

    // Re-calculate locations on window resize and orientation change
    window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
      setupLocations();
    }, false);

    // Highlight active link on the navigation
    var selectActiveMenuItem = function (i) {
      forEach(links, function (i, el) {
        links[i].parentNode.className = links[i].parentNode.className.replace(/[\s]{0,}active/, "");
      });
      links[i].parentNode.className += links[i].parentNode.className ? " active" : "active";
    };

    // Highlight active link when scrolling
    var wasNavigationTapped = false;
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {

      // Determine viewport and body size
      var top = window.pageYOffset,
        body = document.body,
        html = document.documentElement,
        viewport = window.innerHeight,
        bodyheight = Math.max(
          body.scrollHeight,
          body.offsetHeight,
          html.clientHeight,
          html.scrollHeight,
          html.offsetHeight
        );

      // For each content link, when it's in viewport, highlight it
      if (!wasNavigationTapped) {
        forEach(content, function (i, loc) {
          if ((loc > top && (loc < top + 300 || (top + viewport) >= bodyheight))) {
            selectActiveMenuItem(i);
          }
        });
      }
    }, false);

    // Close navigation when tapping the mask under it
    mask.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigation.close();
    }, false);

    // Clear wasNavigationTapped check after scrolling
    var clearTapCheck = function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        wasNavigationTapped = false;
      }, 500);
    };

    // Select the right navigation item when tapping the logo
    document.querySelector(".logo").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      wasNavigationTapped = true;

      // Select first navigation item
      selectActiveMenuItem(0);

      // Close navigation
      navigation.close();

      // Remove hash from the URL if pushState is supported
      if (history.pushState) {
        history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
      }

      // Clear wasNavigationTapped check
      clearTapCheck();
    }, false);

    // When a navigation item is tapped, select it and begin scrolling
    forEach(links, function (i, el) {
      links[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        wasNavigationTapped = true;

        // Select right navigation item (we are passing which one to select "i")
        selectActiveMenuItem(i);

        // Show the URL of the section on the address bar
        var thisID = this.getAttribute("href").replace("#", ""),
          pane = document.getElementById(thisID);

        // If the URL isn't "#home", change it
        if (thisID !== "home") {
          pane.removeAttribute("id");
          location.hash = "#" + thisID;
          pane.setAttribute("id", thisID);

        // If the URL is "#home", remove hash from the URL
        } else {
          if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname);
          }
        }

        // Clear wasNavigationTapped check
        clearTapCheck();
      }, false);
    });

  }

})();
```

Comment: `This is the output when trying to import one of the scripts` how you import the script? As much as I understand all the code you posted here it's their code. We should also see your version to try to identify the the problem. If you could create https://codesandbox.io/s/new, it will be the best